# Python: Import file in grandparent directory

Tags: python, import, module, directory, init

Hierarchy:

```
scripts/
    web/
        script1.py
    tests/
        script2.py
common/
    utils.py
```

How would I import utils in script1 and script2, and still be able to run those scripts seperately (i.e., `python script1.py`). Where would I place the `__init__.py` files, and is that the correct way to go about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
package/
    __init__.py
    scripts/
        web/
            __init__.py
            script1.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            script2.py
    common/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
```

I've added a bunch of empty `__init__.py` files to your package.  Now you have 2 choices, you can use an absolute import:

```
 from package.common import utils
```

or equivalently:

```
 import package.common.utils as utils
```

The downside here is that `package` must somehow be on `PYTHONPATH`.  The other option is to use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports):

```
from ....common import utils
```

I would generally discourage this approach... It just gets too hard to tell where things are coming from (is that 4 periods or 6?).

Comment: When I try running script1.py using the relative import, I get the error:
`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: That's because when you run it as a stand-alone program, python doesn't know it's in a package (It didn't get there by following a trail of `__init__.py` files).  This is another reason why I prefer the more explicit version.

Comment: Hmmm so I just tried using absolute imports, and now it can't find the module. What do I have to do to `PYTHONPATH`? Thanks!

Comment: @JaredZoneraich -- That depends on your OS.  On *NIX using sh as you shell, it would be something like `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/package`

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway that I can accomplish this without changing env variables?

Comment: You can also append to the python path before you try to import the module:  `import sys; sys.path.append('path/to/package'); import package`

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) answer to get more insight.